# What is the use of char* in the container_of macro?

Tags: c

We have the linked list implementation of container_of as follows:

```
 #define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({
 const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
 (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );
 })
```

Can someone explain the purpose of char *? I can see that you are taking an offset yet why is it casted to char * and not to the actual type itself?

Comment: Pointer math. If it's a `char *`, then adding and subtracting pointers gets actual bytes. If they were `int *`, for example, the answer would be scaled by 4 (or whatever the size of an int is).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I didn't know that a char * automatically converts pointers to bytes in calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add and subtract pointers in C, it's done in *units* of the size of the type pointed to. So, for example, if

```
int s[10];
```

if `s` points to an `int`, then `s+1` points to the next `int`, not the next byte. Likewise, if you subtract one pointer from another you get the distance between them in terms of the their type, not bytes.

So `offsetof` casts the pointers to `char *` so that it always returns offsets in terms of bytes.